# Increase starting value of generated keys with hibernate and postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I launched a webapp that uses JPA/Hibernate with a Postgres DB. I want to increase the lower bound for generated keys, so the site doesn't look so "new."

How can I do this with hibernate and/or postgres? I know in MySQL you can set the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT, and I'm looking for a similar feature. Any solution is fine, whether its a hibernate config ( I'm using annotations ) or a one time thing I can diddle in the DB to make future keys start higher.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using sequences in postgresql.

You have to go through every of them and set the next value to be higher:

`ALTER SEQUENCE serial RESTART WITH 105;`

`105` is the new id.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this can be edited from pgadmin by editing the properties for the sequence.